# Matlab Function Errors

Tags: matlab, function, methods

I am not having any luck getting functions to work with the BCGTrain.mat data.  I have tried many different functions and data types and always seem to get a variation of the below error.

> ??? Undefined function or method 'discretize' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Typically when I have received this error it is due to using a function that was not available in the R2011a version of matlab.  I have been able to find older methods and functions that worked.  This time the error is showing up for functions that matlab designates as being available before R2006a.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Please let me know if I can try something out, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: When googling the function [discretize](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html), you find in the documentation of Matlab that it was introduced in R2015a. So which version do you have/ are you using of Matlab??

Answer (score 0):

Type `doc function` into the command window, if nothing shows up then that function is not included in your version of MATLAB.